# ASP.NET GridView - How to have an ImageField when AutoGenerateColumns is true

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with a lot of columns, auto-generated from a class:

```
class GVModel {
  public int Id { get { ... } }
  public string Name { get { ... } }
  //...
}
```

How can I add a small thumbnail? (ie. add an ImageField as an extra column)

I tried this but it has no effect:

```
class GVModel {
  public int Id { get { ... } }
  public string Name { get { ... } }
  //...
  public Image Image { get { return Image.FromFile(...); } }
}
```

Comment: You can use object data type :

public object TrendPicture { get; set; }

Comment: U can refer this link also : http://forums.asp.net/t/1892831.aspx/1?What+to+do+to+add+image+field+in+the+model+class

Comment: Thanks Janki, but that won't work when using AutoGenerateColumns

Answer (score 0):

If your no. of columns for the GridView is fixed (as it seems), then set AutoGenerateColumns to false, add as many columns as required, set their DataText property to the name of column of the class, and in the last, add a template field containing an asp:Image, set it's src to the appropriate column of the class.

And in the class definition, instead of using an image datatype, use a string representing the url of that image.